# Odd Bernoulli numbers are zero using functional equation of Bernoulli Polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

Let $(B_k)$ denote the sequence of Bernoulli numbers and let $B_n(x):=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}B_k x^{n-k} $ denote the Bernoulli polynomials. Bernoulli Polynomials satisfy the following functional equation:

$$B_n(x+1)-B_n(x) = n\cdot x^{n-1},$$

for all $n\in\mathbb{N}, x\in\mathbb{R}$, and $B_n=B_{n}(0)=B_{n}(1)$ are the Bernoulli numbers. It is well known that that the odd Bernoulli numbers vanish, i.e. $B_{2k+1}=0$ for all $k\geq 1$.

I think that this statement should follow very elementary from the above functional equation, but I could not prove it yet. I would be very happy if someone can show me an elementary proof using that functional equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we need also the symmetry
$$B_n(1-x)=(-1)^n B_n(x).$$
Then, by letting $x=0$ into the two functional equations we get:
$$B_n(0+1)-B_n(0) = n\cdot 0^{n-1}=0\quad\mbox{and}\quad B_n(1-0)=(-1)^n B_n(0).$$
Finally, if $n$ is odd then
$$B_n(1)=B_n(0)\quad\mbox{and}\quad B_n(1)=-B_n(0)\implies B_n(0)=0.$$

Comment: Thank you! How do you prove the symmetry (your first equation)

Comment: You may use the generating function: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_Bernoulli_Polynomial

Comment: Yes, but I was looking for a more elementary proof.

Comment: Which definition of Bernoulli polynomial are you using?

Comment: $B_n(x):=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}B_k x^{n-k}$

Comment: The generating function can be easily determined from the definition that you are using. See Lemma 2 here: https://dms.umontreal.ca/~mlalin/bernoulli.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the most direct way to see that $B_{2k+1}=0$ ($k>0$) is to recall the generating function 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{t}{e^t-1}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_n t^n}{n!}
\end{eqnarray*}
And now observe that the function
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(t)=\frac{t}{e^t-1} + \frac{t}{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
satisfies $f(t)=f(-t)$ and so is even.

Comment: Yes that is true. I am wondering if there is a more "elementary" proof, e.g. using only the functional equation given above.

Comment: I just thought it would be nice to contrast this with Roberts answer. I can delete it if you like. $\ddot \smile$